# Como criar um union type a partir dos elementos de um tipo de array em TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, tipagem

Tenho este código:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

interface data ...
```

Como faço para pegar o conteúdo do `array` e tipo no data? Como se fosse assim:

```
interface data {
    numbers: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
}
```

PS: Eu **não** quero tipar o array, eu quero tipar o conteúdo do array, ou seja, eu não quero isso:

```
interface data {
    numbers: number[]
}
```

Comment: `interface data{
  numbers: int[];
}` é isso que quer saber?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Não

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu quero que ele pegue os valores do array e use como tipo

Comment: mas que tipo? não é um array de inteiros? seria isso `int[]`, ou você quer transformar o array numa string separa por pipe (`|`) ?

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu quero pegar os elementos do array e tipá-los, e não o array em si

Comment: não da pra fazer isso numa interface... o array deveria ser já de um tipo certo, como `int` ou `string`, se não sabe o que vai vir no array só poder `object` , então na interface deveria ser `any[]`, e quem vai tipar tem de ser a implementação, a class

Comment: @RicardoPontual, na verdade, dá sim! :-) [Veja.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/495157/69296)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode obter uma união com todos os tipos do array utilizando a notação de colchetes. Assim:

```
type MyArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// %inferred-type: 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
type MyArrUnion = MyArr[number];
```

<sup>Veja no [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCCAnRUC8UDaBGANFATHgMx4AseArALoDcAUHQPSNQCkAlgHYBmEyEAEwC0oSAC4oFKAB8oWGQQVEFpOqOhwkiAKqd2Ae05pYCZBk4BXALYAjPrSA).</sup>

Note que, nesse caso, o tipo do array é estático. Se você precisar obter o tipo a partir de um array já existente, utilize o operador `typeof` (no contexto de tipagem estática). Exemplo:

```
const myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] as const; // Note que a asserção `as const` foi necessária para preservar o tipo estático que colocamos.

type MyArr = typeof myArr;

// %inferred-type: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
type MyArrUnion = MyArr[number];
```

<sup>Veja no [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwIICcUwLwwNoEYA0MATIQMyEAshArALowCGEMokUA3DAPRcwByIKAFMYARwCuIhowgQhKAOcBjkDAAGTFuGhqYAMxABLGGCHAhsgIcpD0gA4MU9lBfkA3RzFVRDd1RahLH1AxSS0AGxBgBjgQCAA6AChEqAQ7EQBZZDRMGFT0kD14bJR2ZJ4YAFJDMD15FwATAFp8oQAuGFwYAB9iHphSfop%206hS0zJKAVTBDcFys1BRsMHE4ACN5WnYgA).</sup>

E se o tipo inferido de `MyArr` fosse algo como `number[]`, `MyArr[number]` também funcionaria, só que seria inferido o tipo `number`.